# Finding XPATH in c# selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I couldnt find this element by xpath. I need help about it. I m using c# selenium. İts twitter login email vertification modal window. Im trying to send an email to this input.

```
<input class="r-30o5oe r-1niwhzg r-17gur6a r-1yadl64 r-deolkf r-t60dpp r-1dz5y72 r-fdjqy7 r- 
12qz1uu" autocapitalize="none" autocomplete="on" autocorrect="off"
inputmode="text" name="text" spellcheck="false" type="text" dir="auto" value="">
```

Comment: While I am not very familiar with the xpath syntax, If I may suggest you can try to find by css selector instead which would be "input[name='username']" in this case. You can verify this by executing document.querySelector("input[name='username']") in browser console. In C# selenium bindings,  you can use - By.CssSelector("input[name='username']")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below `xPath's` to find the element.

`xPath` with `inputmode`:

```
//input[@inputmode='text']
```

`xPath` with `name`:

```
//input[@name='text']
```

`xPath` with `type`:

```
//input[@type='text']
```

Always check your `xPath` in chrome console to make sure it is unique.

- Press `F12` in Chrome.
- Go to `elements` section
- Search ( `CTRL + F`)
- Place the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node. This means, your `xPath` is unique.